# Extraer los caracteres de "image/png" despues del ' / ' con PHP

Tags: php, string

Necesito extraer sólo los caracteres que están despues de el / en mi string: "image/png", es decir el **png**, con PHP

Estoy tratando de capturarlos con un var_dump por el momento, es de una imagen que estoy cargando en un formulario, de la sgte manera:

```
var_dump($_FILES["datosImagen"]["type"]);
```

Pero no sé con qué método extraer sólo lo que está después del /

*Cabe resaltar que ese valor es oscilatorio.*

Comment: Gracias, pero es una pregunta que no necesita gran cosa para ser formulada, para un buen entendedor y/o programador, pocas palabras bastan. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer usa de la función `explode()` de PHP que genera un array de un `string` que le pases como argumento.

Dado tu ejemplo el caracter de separación es el símbolo de la `/` entonces tu código puede quedar así

```
<?php

$imagen = 'image/png';

$data = explode("/", $imagen);

echo $data[1];
```

Que me da como resultado en pantalla

> png

Le indico que acceda a la posición 1, por que como mencioné antes esta función genera un array del string que le pases como argumento, mira lo siguiente

```
<?php

$imagen = 'image/png';

var_dump(explode("/", $imagen));
```

Que me da como resultado lo siguiente

> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "image" [1]=> string(3) "png" }

Donde como puedes ver la posición 0 la ocupa `image` y la posición 1 la ocupa `png`

Aquí mas información en [la documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)